# What Function has these 4 Properties?

Tags: calculus, functions

Two questions:

1) Find a function $g$ so that:

- The domain of $g$ is at least $(0, \infty)$
- $g$ is continuous on its domain
- $g$ is concave up on its domain
- $\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x) = -\infty$

I'm confused about how properties 3 and 4 can happen at the same time? Can somebody help with what function this might be?

2) Find a function $h$ so that

- The domain of $h$ is $(-\infty, \infty)$
- $h$ has no max
- $h$ has no min
- The sup of $h$ on its domain is 2
- The inf of $h$ on its domain is 0

Not, sure how to deal with having no max and min at the same time.

Comment: How about $g(x)=-\ln(x+1)$ or $-\sqrt x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $g$ is differentiable. Properties $3$ and $4$ imply then that $g$ is decreasing but $g''(x)>0$.

Several examples exist, $g=-x$ and $g=-\ln x$ being two of them.

---

Having no maximum or minimum, yet having a supremum and infimum, means that $0$ and $2$ are horizontal asymptotes for $h$. An example satisfying the conditions is $h(x)=2\cdot\frac1{1+e^{-x}}$, a sigmoid function.

Comment: Another one: $f$ has a local min at $x = 0$ and an inflection point at $x = 0$. What function is this?

Comment: @SeptemberSummers $f(x)=|x|$. An inflection point is actually independent of differentiability at the point.

Answer (score 1):

1. $g(x)=-\ln(x+1)$ or $=\sqrt x$
2. $h(x)=\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2+1}+x-1}x$